# Jersey client.setChunkedEncodingSize(null) not working

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey-1.0

I am writing one client to measure Jersey, REST based web service performance. I have written some code to measure response time and to measure number of bytes sent from the server but `response.getLength()` method always returning `-1`.

In many QA forum I read that setting `client.setChunkedEncodingSize(null)` will work but even after setting this, I am getting -1.

From server side, I am sending response of type XML or JSON or protobuf depending upon parameters sent by client. For all of these response types, I am getting response length as -1.

My actual request looks like below:

```
WebResource webResourceQuery = client.resource(requestUrl);
ClientResponse response = webResourceQuery.header("Authorization", header)
                                          .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                          .get(ClientResponse.class);
```

From server side, I am not setting content-length explicitly. Can anyone please help me in getting content-length on client side?

Whole purpose of this experiment is to measure which response type is more efficient in terms of response time and amount of data sent/received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran in to the same problem: `client.setChunkedEncodingSize(null);` does not work.

This worked for me to actually disable chunked encoding:

```
client.getProperties().put(ApacheHttpClient4Config.PROPERTY_ENABLE_BUFFERING, true);
```